# Are generic.list and generic.dictionary thread safe in .net

Tags: .net, multithreading, generics, collections, thread-safety

How do we know whether a method is thread safe or not

For example, if I check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1.aspx there is nothing that indicates its thread-safety.

Comment: Assume a class is not thread safe unless it's documented as such.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, they are not thread safe (without performing your own locking).

Use one of the [Concurrent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx) collections instead.

[Thread-Safe Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305.aspx)

> The System.Collections.Concurrent namespace provides several
>   thread-safe collection classes that should be used in place of the
>   corresponding types in the System.Collections and
>   System.Collections.Generic namespaces whenever multiple threads are
>   accessing the collection concurrently.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2009/02/11/why-are-thread-safe-collections-so-hard.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for the entire [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) class has a segment on thread safety:

> Public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

Comment: True as this may be, this is boilerplate documentation that's on virtually every (if not every) .NET type.

Comment: Good to point out. That explains why there is no concurentList. List is already concurrent. +1

Comment: Actually no. There is no indicator that it's thread safe. List doesn't seem to contain any static method.

Comment: @JimThio That's not what the documentation means. It means that if `List` had *static* methods, they would be threadsafe in that they wouldn't change any global state. It is *not* safe to share instances of `List` between threads without synchronisation, because you always need to call their instance methods to actually work with them.

Comment: @JimThio You're looking for [`SynchronizedCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668265.aspx)